# Json encode PHP array decoding it to a json string

Tags: php, json

I json_encode the following ($output) array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [month] => January 2014
        [posts] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [month] => December 2013
        [posts] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [month] => August 2013
        [posts] => 1
    )
)

<?php $json = json_encode($output); ?>
```

I then print it to the console to check it:

```
<script>    
var myjson = <?php echo $json; ?>;
console.log(myjson);
</script>
```

In the console, 'myjson' is formed like thus:

```
[Object { month="January 2014", posts=2}, 
Object { month="December 2013", posts=1}, 
Object { month="August 2013", posts=1}] --------------------------($)
```

an array of objects. Whereas I need it to be like:

```
[{
"Month": "Jan 2014",
"Posts": 2,
}, {
"Month": "Dec 2013",
"Posts": 1,
}, {
"Month": "Aug 2013",
"Posts": 1,
}];
```

a json string. If I can somehow remove the 'Object' syntax and instead of '=', there would be colons, I'm good. Looking around on this site
and trying various methods:

```
<?php
 $json = json_encode(array_values($output));
 $json = json_encode(array_values($output),true);
 $json = json_encode($output,true);
?>
```

I've read about lot's of people having the same difficulty but all solutions tend to be very specific in nature. So my question would be,
given any two-dimensional array how do I json_encode it in order to give me or return a json string in javascript?

If I run ($) through http://jsonlint.com/ it returns:

```
Parse error on line 1:
[    Object{        url=
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in fact, giving you the proper JSON; however, you're echoing the whole thing without delimiters and so it is parsed. If you want the string literal to appear in your console log as a string simple put the output between delimiters:

```
<script>
  var myjson = '<?php echo $json ?>';
  console.log(myjson);
</script>
```

Comment: No probs, also don't forget to escape if needed (i.e. if you potentially have `'` in your data)

Answer (score 0):

Try [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/):

```
<script>    
var myjson = $.parseJSON(<?php echo $json; ?>);
console.log(myjson);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
<script>    
    var myjson = JSON.stringify(<?= $json; ?>, null, 2);
    console.log(myjson);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put " around the keys for the array, so for example;

Instead of:

```
$output[][Month] = "January 2014"
```

type:

```
$output[]["Month"] = "January 2014"
$output[]["Posts"] = "2"
```

Then in the program that is receiving the json object, you can do a loop..

```
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    var thisElement = myArray[i];
    myMonth = thisElement["Month"];
    myPosts = thisElement["Posts"];
 }
```

Alternatively, if you're using angular (like i was which was how i learned json formatting);

When receiving it;

```
$scope.MonthInfo = data

//on your html page
<div ng-repeat="monthLoop in MonthInfo"> {{monthLoop.Month}} {{monthLoop.Posts}}</div>
```

Hope this helps somehow :)